# Boot arch from usb stick

Tags: linux, arch-linux, windows, usb, tails-os

I am currently running windows 10 on my computer and looking into running Linux. I do not want to make the jump and potentially lose data and for my steam games to stop working. Is there any way I can side boot a distro such as arch from a usb stick similar to how tails Linux operates when you boot into the OS? Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: You could also run a virtual machine (VMWare, VirtualBox, etc) to install a Un\*x-like operating system to learn with.

Comment: I've considered that but I would like Linux to be separate from my windows install so it is only using free software

Comment: Several virtual machine applications have free/community editions which are free, for this purpose. You could even set them up as a "portable app" USB to plug in and run from any suitable machine. Within the VM, it _is_ separate from host, and "using free software" has no bearing.

Comment: So the host machine is completely separated from the virtual machine?

Comment: "Logically", yes. The host is the physical computer. The guest is the virtual computer. The guest can have it's own virtual hardware, even hardware that the host does not--Video game emulators operate in a similar manner. Depending on the VM software, they can share--or not share--hardware such as network adapters, disk drives, video displays, and anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archlinux does not have 'live' disk images like other distros which provide graphical environment and are ready to use by general public. You can boot archlinux installation image, but it has only command line (technically you can test how minimal arch linux installation looks like, but it has no graphical environment). You can boot from installation image and install archlinux on external disk or usb flash (it would be very slow) and then install graphical environment to that partion (external disk/usb). In this case you will have archlinux installation which does not risk your main drive. It should be also noted that archlinux requires technical skills to install and is not suitable for beginners.

Comment: are there any beginner friendly distros similar to tails?

Comment: There are plenty of distributions targeted for beginners, but I am not sure about similar to tails.

Answer (score 0):

Just to report from my expierence. more than 10 years ago I started using arch and I started using a USB Stick for it.

I stoped doing that because it was to slow in the end. Even a ssd in a external case is a better option. So don't be too disapointed. Also you NEED to minimize writes to the device. For an USB Stick this is much more crucial then for an SSD!

In terms of getting ist work , you might need to put some of your harware specific hooks in /etc/mkinitcpio.conf, so the usb-chips are ready prior to boot.

from that file:

3 # The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
4 # run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
5 # in this array.  For instance:
6 #     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
7 MODULES=(sd_mod ext4 xhci_pci ahci igb amdgpu)

But which hardware hooks you need depend on your computer...